# dFdx(FragPos) generates performance warning

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am using [`dFdx()` function](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/dFdx.xhtml) in the fagment shader to generate a flat shading.

I noticed that this code generates the warning message below. Should I worry about it, what does it mean and whether it has to do anything with performance?

```
Debug message (2): API_ID_RECOMPILE_FRAGMENT_SHADER performance warning has been generated. Fragment shader recompiled due to state change.
Source: API
Type: Performance
Severity: medium
```

My code in the fragment shader:

```c
//flat shading
vec3 x_ = dFdx(FragPos);
vec3 y_= dFdy(FragPos);
vec3 normal_ = cross(x_, y_);
vec3 norm_ = normalize(normal_);
```

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].  Feel free to use [this](https://github.com/genpfault/glfw-mcve-base/blob/master/src/main.cpp) as a base.

Comment: *"Fragment shader recompiled due to state change."* is not directly caused by `dFdx`/`dFdy`. You have changed a state after compiling and linking the shader, which causes the shader to be recompiled. The shader is optimized for the states present at the time of its generation. Later state changes may cause recompilation due to optimization for the new conditions.

Comment: I wondering why, because if I remove these two lines no errors appears.

Comment: This is not an error, but a warning. Changing the shader code can make it independent of certain states. Try to create the shader later in the code. If you create the shader after setting the state that causes the issue, your problem will be solved.

Comment: I changed the code. No I initialize the shader only once. If I draw many meshes I get this warning only once. I initialize shader in the draw while loop glUseProgram(ID), I cannot initialize it before, else all different shaders gets mixed up. This message is printed after line 198 " glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, static_cast<unsigned int>(indices.size()), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);" Would you have time to take a look at the full code? https://github.com/petrasvestartas/CMAKE/blob/main/super_build/example_glfw/build/install/viewer/opengl_meshes.h